# Pandas groupby data from the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe (it's much longer, I only put here the first five elements):

|  | show_id | type | title | director | cast | country | date_added | release_year | rating | duration | listed_in | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | s1 | TV Show | 3% | Henley Hii | João Miguel... | Brazil | August 14, 1992 | 1992 | TV-MA | 4 Seasons | International TV... | In a... |
| 1 | s2 | Movie | 7:19 | Jorge Michel Grau | Demián Bichir... | Mexico | December 23, 2016 | 2016 | TV-MA | 93 min | Dramas | After a... |
| 2 | s3 | Movie | 23:59 | Gilbert Chan | Tedd Chan... | Singapore | December 20, 2018 | 2011 | R | 78 min | Horror Movies | When an... |
| 3 | s4 | Movie | 9 | Shane Acker | Elijah Wood... | United States | November 16, 2017 | 2009 | PG-13 | 80 min | Action & Adventure... | In a... |
| 4 | s5 | Movie | 21 | Robert Luketic | Jim Sturgess... | United States | January 1, 2020 | 2008 | PG-13 | 123 min | Dramas | A brilliant... |

And I would like to group, *for each year, the number of movies and TV shows, from the year 2000 onwards.*

Disregarding the "from the year 2000" part. The closest I've been is:

```
dt.groupby(['release_year']).agg({'type': 'count'})
```

But it returns the entire dataframe to me, which is not what I need. I've also tried:

```
dt[dt['release_year'] > 2000].groupby(['type'])
```

But it returns exactly the same.

I am lost here. Every example I see allows making a groupby in the columns, but does not allow to make the groups for elements in the same column.

When I try other types of groupby that consider columns as a whole it works perfectly fine. For example:

```
dt.groupby ('rating_cat', as_index=False).agg(['min','mean','max'])`)
```

How do I fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `dt[dt['release_year'] > 2000].groupby(['release_year']).agg({'type': 'count'})`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Could any distinction be made in the `type` column? (instead of one single column for type, one column for 'TV Show' and another column for 'Movie')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of the pandas [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
pd.pivot_table(dt.loc[dt['release_year'] > 2000,['release_year','type']], 
                index='release_year', 
                columns='type', 
                aggfunc=len, 
                fill_value=0)
```